# How to make different behavior when 'select all' is selected on a multivalue parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a reporting services report and a stoproc. The report has a multivalue parameter that is being used like this:

```
<QueryParameter Name="@Aannemer">
  <!-- Joins the multivalue selection into a single comma separated string. -->
  <Value>=Join(Parameters!Aannemers.Value,",")</Value>
  <rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined>
</QueryParameter>
```

The stoproc splits the multivalue parameter using string_split. The stoproc is very long so here is a smaller version of it:

```
    @Aannemer AS NVARCHAR(max) = NULL
[...]

    SELECT DISTINCT PV.ProefvakID
    FROM [dbo].[Proefvak] PV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Meetvak MV ON MV.ProefvakID = PV.ProefvakID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Uitvoerder UI ON UI.UitvoerderID = MV.UitvoerderID
    WHERE (UI.Uitvoerder IN(select value from string_split(@Aannemer,',')) OR @Aannemer IS NULL )
```

This all works like a charm so far.

If a user selects 'select all' for the Aannemer parameter, he wants to see all Proefvak's and not filter on Aannemers at all. 
But if a Proefvak exists that has no Meetvak connected to it, the Proefvak will never be listed (because the Meetvak holds the Uitvoerder and the Proefvak has no Meetvak). The user still wants to see the Proefvak that has no Meetvak.

Is there a way to check in the stoproc whether the user has selected 'select all', so I can return all Proefvak's?

I hope you understand what I am trying to accomplish. I am a noob when it comes to SQL, so please be clear with the complex parts. Thanks in advance!

==EDIT==
Trying to use @EddiGordo's solution, that looks promising. The next problem is that the @Aannemer parameter does not include the value 'Select All', because this is not a real value. So I tried to edit the code on the SSRS side like this:

```
<QueryParameter Name="@Aannemer">
            <!-- Joins the multivalue selection into a single comma separated string. This paramater should be split up in the stored procedure. -->
            <Value>
              =IIF(Parameters!Aannemers.Count = COUNT(1, "Aannemers")
              , "Select All", 
              Join(Parameters!Aannemers.Value,","))
            </Value>
            <rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined>
          </QueryParameter>
```

But I cannot deploy the SSRS code like this, I get this error:
"The expression used for the parameter '@Aannemer' in the dataset '@Aannemer' includes an aggregate or lookup function. Aggregate and lookup functions cannot be used in query parameter expressions."

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF @Aannemer IS NULL  
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT PV.ProefvakID
    FROM [dbo].[Proefvak] PV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Meetvak MV ON MV.ProefvakID = PV.ProefvakID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Uitvoerder UI ON UI.UitvoerderID = MV.UitvoerderID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT PV.ProefvakID
    FROM [dbo].[Proefvak] PV
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Meetvak MV ON MV.ProefvakID = PV.ProefvakID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Uitvoerder UI ON UI.UitvoerderID = MV.UitvoerderID
    WHERE UI.Uitvoerder IN(select value from string_split(@Aannemer,','))
END
```

Comment: User ask for taking 'Select All' value as if it was null value. You do not answer the question.

Comment: @EddiGordo that's exactly what I mean. I'm SO glad you understand me and put what I mean into one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

try changing :

```
OR @Aannemer IS NULL
```

by

```
OR nullIf(@Aannemer, 'Select All') Is Null
```

in the where clause of your *IN(Select...* condition

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Are you sure the value 'Select All' is in the comma separated string when a users selects 'Select All'?

Comment: No, i don't know what the value of "Select All" is. You have to check it and modify nullIf statement accordingly. Maybe empty string ("")?